# Can't type ] in Visual Studio because that puts lines in comment

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, visual-studio, resharper

**Background**

My Windows 7 is installed under language and keyboard settings `Dutch (Belgium)` and apparently it's not possible to use `]` *(right square bracket)*, because that puts lines in comment (as I am under VB.Net, it adds ' to the start of the line).

**What I tried**

I tried to set the language to `English (United States)`, but then I can't type `]` either. Nothing happens, in that case.

**My environment**

```
Visual Studio 2013
Resharper 9.0
Windows 7
```

**Question**

Any ideas on how to fix this so I can type `]` without anything else happening?

*PS: `]` works fine in other programs.*

Comment: Have you been to `Tools > Options > Environment > International Settings` and made sure that is set to English? And not "The same as windows"?

Comment: It was at `English` already.

Comment: I assume you are using an AZERY keyboard (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY) and need to press the `AltGr`+`$` to get the `]`? On my UK keyboard, pressing `AltGr` converts to `CTRL`+`ALT` in Visual Studio so your combination may not work. Maybe you could use a US/UK keyboard for programming.

Comment: @PiersMyers: Correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Visual Studio, under `Tools`->`Options...`->`Environment`->`Keyboard`, in the 'Press shortcut keys:' box press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd> (as this is how you get the ']' on your AZERTY keyboard), this will probably convert to `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`$` and this will show you what command it is mapped to.

Just remove or rebind the shortcut that comes up.